# SQL Optimization, Does conditions on column list affect optimization?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I don't think the title is clear enough (please suggest)

Say I have this hypothetical query

```
  SELECT
    Name,
    P.Amount,
    count(DISTINCT PI.Id)
  FROM Customer C
    LEFT JOIN Purchase P ON C.Id = P.CustomerId
    LEFT JOIN Flags F ON P.Id = F.PurchaseId AND F.Name = 'showItems'
    LEFT JOIN PurchseItems PI ON PI.PurchseId = P.Id AND F.Value = 'TRUE'
  WHERE C.Id = @customerId
  GROUP BY Name, P.Amount, F.Value
```

and alternatively

```
SELECT
  Name,
  P.Amount,
  CASE WHEN F.Value = 'TRUE' THEN count(DISTINCT PI.Id) ELSE 0 END As ItemsCount
FROM Customer C
  LEFT JOIN Purchase P ON C.Id = P.CustomerId
  LEFT JOIN Flags F ON P.Id = F.PurchaseId AND F.Name = 'showItems'
  LEFT JOIN PurchseItems PI ON PI.PurchseId = P.Id
WHERE C.Id = @customerId
GROUP BY Name, P.Amount, F.Value
```

Would one or the other help the query optimizer in anyway. I'm using MS SQL server. I want to know if conditions on the column list makes a difference?

---

My guess is that if `F.Value` is not `'True'` the query wouldn't have to go through joining `PurchaseItems` at all.

---

#### Edit: Added `F.Value` in Group by because it's unique per Purchase

I didn't move it the count close to keep the query more or less the same. The idea of the question is to compare conditions on joins vs on select list.

Comment: Of course you could check the differences yourself, simply run both queries. Assuming there's a GROUP BY  your 2nd query will not run at all, it should be `COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN F.Value = 'TRUE' THEN PI.Id END As ItemsCount`. Otherwise the condition has to be checked anyway and the most expensive operation will be the DISTINCT.

Comment: @dnoeth you forgot to close your parenthesis in your SQL. :)

Comment: You'll get better performance if you SELECT....FROM (SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer WHERE Id = @customerId) AS C..... instead of putting the parameter way down in the WHERE clause.

Comment: You cannot have an aggregate with no group by.  Write queries that work and compare the execution plans.

Comment: @EricBrandt: If there's any difference I would consider it a bug. But as this is counting a column from an inner table those Outer joins can probably be replaced by Inner joins.

Comment: @paparazzo Added group by. And the query was there to show  a hypothetical situation.

Comment: @dnoeth I don't understand you first comment. Do you mean if I move the query inside `COUNT` I would get a better performance out of the second query?

Comment: Still not valid syntax.

Comment: And I don't get why it was down voted twice.

Comment: @paparazzo where is the error?

Comment: Down vote because it is not valid syntax.  Take the effort to build some real tables, test data, and valid queries and examine the query plans.  Build a real query and see the error for yourself.

Comment: @paparazzo I have a real query that works. I changed entity names because my employers may not approve of it. And I can't test because I can't seed enough data and I wouldn't understand query plan because I'm not an expert on that

Comment: OK you have a *real* query that works?  Have you tested the queries you posted.

Comment: When you move the CASE into the COUNT you will get a *working* query, currently you'll simply get an error message: *Msg 8120 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
Column 'F.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Comment: @paparazzo Only tested one of them, I came up with the other as an alternative and didn't test it. I'm sorry for my mistake, I was going for a hypocritical question to get a theoretical answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first query is better than second provided there are some record where F.Value <> 'TRUE'

First query will filter the record to the point or less records.so query will be fast.

Actual number of rows will be less.

Second query will fetch more resultset ,then again you apply case statement to get correct ItemCount.

Actual number of rows will be more.

Not  commenting on rest of your query or requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In general:
The more specific you can make the SELECTION (ON clause and WHERE clause), the more handles you give the optimizer to optimise on.
On this bases your first query should be the best query.

Run both queries with :

-- dbcc dropcleanbuffers       -- Cleans the cache of data.

-- dbcc freeproccache          -- Cleans the cache of coding.

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SET STATISTICS IO  ON

To get an impression about the cost of the query.

Ben